# Is it possible to model recursion with requestanimationframe?

Tags: javascript, recursion, maze

I am creating a maze generation function, which requires uses recursive backtracking and *obviously* requires recursion. The function has to be run `length * breath` times, which sometimes exceeds the maximum recursion depth. The following is the code for the maze:

```js
function maze(width, height){
    var grid = []; 
    
    for (var y = 0; y < height; y++){
        grid.push([]); 
        for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) grid[y].push(0); 
    }
    
    function shuffle(){
        var result = ["N", "S", "E", "W"]; 
        
        for (var count = result.length; count > 0; count--){
            rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * count); 
            [result[count - 1], result[rand]] = [result[rand], result[count - 1]]; 
        }
    
        return result; 
    }
    
    function carve(curr_x, curr_y){
        for (var dir of shuffle()){
            var new_x = curr_x + {N: 0, S: 0, E: 1, W: -1}[dir], new_y = curr_y + {N: -1, S: 1, E: 0, W: 0}[dir]; 
            
            if (new_y >= 0 && new_y <= height - 1 && new_x >= 0 && new_x <= width - 1 && grid[new_y][new_x] == 0){
                grid[curr_y][curr_x] += {N: 1, S: 2, E: 4, W: 8}[dir]; 
                grid[new_y][new_x] += {N: 2, S: 1, E: 8, W: 4}[dir]; 
                carve(new_x, new_y); 
            }
        }
    }

    carve(Math.floor(width / 3) + Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(2 / 3 * width)), Math.floor(height / 3) + Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(2 / 3 * height))); 

    return grid;  
}
```

Given the definition of recursion, I believe that this function can be rewritten in `requestAnimationFrame`, so that the maximum recursion depth will not be exceeded. Is it possible? Are there any methods to convert recursion to something else? Thank you!

Comment: Any recursive code can be expressed iteratively (and vice versa.)  The usual technique is to manually manage a stack of the operations in progress and simply `while`-loop until your base case is reached, pushing onto and popping from the stack as you go.  If, as it looks like, you don't need to maintain separate states, and everything is just modifying a single structure, then, yes you could also do this with repeated asynchronous calls of some sort, but I don't see how you would gain much in doing so.  Also, I'm curious how the grids you generate represent mazes.

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` should be used for animation and nothing else

Comment: How large (`width`, `height`) is your grid? I wouldn't expect this to exceed the max stack size.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, I think the numbers define where the walls are if you look at their 4 0s and 1s in binary. E.g.: https://jsfiddle.net/6Lgc45n9/

Comment: @user3297291: Ah, that makes sense.  Hadn't seen that before.  I knew there was something binary going on, of course, with 1, 2, 4, 8, but it wasn't clear.

Comment: If your `maze` function calls `requestAnimationFrame`, then the callback won't happen until after `maze` returns -- that's not gonna be useful unless you can make `maze` an async function that returns a `Promise` instead of the finished maze.  Does that work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of your code refactored to run in a single while loop. I'm not sure if there's a specific approach to it, but just showing you the code might help...

This is the main part:

```js
let pos = start;
let revisit = [];

while (pos) {
  const next = randomEmptyAdjacent(pos);  
  if (next) {
    carve(pos, next);
    revisit.push(pos); // Mark this cell for revisiting
    pos = next;        // Go depth-first
  } else {
    pos = revisit.pop();
  }
}
```

Using a `requestAnimationFrame` or `setTimeout` to kind of escape the stack is never a good idea. It will make the code run slow.

### Example

Here's the thing in a runnable snippet. I added visualization of the maze to make it easy to check the output.

```js
function maze(width, height) {
  const grid = [];
  const start = [
    Math.floor(width / 3) + Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(2 / 3 * width)),
    Math.floor(height / 3) + Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(2 / 3 * height))
  ];

  for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    grid.push([]);
    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) grid[y].push(0);
  }

  const randomEmptyAdjacent = ([y, x]) => {
    const available = [
      [y - 1, x], // top
      [y, x + 1], // right
      [y + 1, x], // bottom
      [y, x - 1] // left
    ].filter(
      ([y, x]) => (
        y >= 0 && y <= height - 1 &&
        x >= 0 && x <= width - 1 &&
        grid[y][x] === 0
      )
    );

    return available[Math.floor(Math.random() * available.length)];
  }

  const carve = (from, to) => {
    const [y1, x1] = from;
    const [y2, x2] = to;
    const dy = y2 - y1;
    const dx = x2 - x1;

    if (dy === 1) {
      grid[y1][x1] += 2;
      grid[y2][x2] += 1;
    } else if (dy === -1) {
      grid[y1][x1] += 1;
      grid[y2][x2] += 2;
    }

    if (dx === 1) {
      grid[y1][x1] += 4;
      grid[y2][x2] += 8;
    } else if (dx === -1) {
      grid[y1][x1] += 8;
      grid[y2][x2] += 4;
    }
  }

  let pos = start;
  let revisit = [];

  while (pos) {
    const next = randomEmptyAdjacent(pos);
    if (next) {
      carve(pos, next);
      revisit.push(pos);
      pos = next;
    } else {
      pos = revisit.pop();
    }
  }

  return grid;
}

const renderMaze = maze => {
  const h = maze.length;
  const w = maze[0].length;
  const S = 10;

  const mazeEl = document.querySelector(".maze");
  mazeEl.innerHTML = "";

  mazeEl.style.width = `${w * S}px`;
  mazeEl.style.height = `${h * S}px`;

  for (const row of maze) {
    for (const cell of row) {
      const cellEl = document.createElement("div");
      cellEl.classList.add("cell");

      if (cell & 8) {
        cellEl.style.borderLeftColor = "transparent";
      }

      if (cell & 4) {
        cellEl.style.borderRightColor = "transparent";
      }

      if (cell & 2) {
        cellEl.style.borderBottomColor = "transparent";
      }

      if (cell & 1) {
        cellEl.style.borderTopColor = "transparent";
      }

      cellEl.style.width = `${S - 2}px`;
      cellEl.style.height = `${S - 2}px`;
      mazeEl.appendChild(cellEl);
    }
  }
}

const m = maze(50, 50);

renderMaze(m);
```

```css
.maze {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.cell {
  flex: none;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="maze"></div>
```

### Animations!

Just for fun, here's an example of what `requestAnimationFrame` is useful for: animating stuff! This snippet generates the maze in a single loop, but uses `requestAnimationFrame` to queue the rendering of a cell to be drawn frame-by-frame.

```js
function maze(width, height) {
  const start = [
    Math.floor(width / 3) + Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(2 / 3 * width)),
    Math.floor(height / 3) + Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(2 / 3 * height))
  ];

  const grid = [];
  const S = 6;
  const mazeEl = document.querySelector(".maze");
  mazeEl.innerHTML = "";

  mazeEl.style.width = `${width * S}px`;
  mazeEl.style.height = `${height * S}px`;

  for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    grid.push([]);
    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
      grid[y].push(0);
      const cellEl = document.createElement("div");
      cellEl.style.width = `${S - 2}px`;
      cellEl.style.height = `${S - 2}px`;
      cellEl.classList.add("cell");
      mazeEl.appendChild(cellEl);
    }
  }

  const randomEmptyAdjacent = ([y, x]) => {
    const available = [
      [y - 1, x], // top
      [y, x + 1], // right
      [y + 1, x], // bottom
      [y, x - 1] // left
    ].filter(
      ([y, x]) => (
        y >= 0 && y <= height - 1 &&
        x >= 0 && x <= width - 1 &&
        grid[y][x] === 0
      )
    );

    return available[Math.floor(Math.random() * available.length)];
  }

  const carve = (from, to) => {
    const [y1, x1] = from;
    const [y2, x2] = to;
    const dy = y2 - y1;
    const dx = x2 - x1;

    if (dy === 1) {
      grid[y1][x1] += 2;
      grid[y2][x2] += 1;
    } else if (dy === -1) {
      grid[y1][x1] += 1;
      grid[y2][x2] += 2;
    }

    if (dx === 1) {
      grid[y1][x1] += 4;
      grid[y2][x2] += 8;
    } else if (dx === -1) {
      grid[y1][x1] += 8;
      grid[y2][x2] += 4;
    }

    queue(
      mazeEl.children[y1 * width + x1], grid[y1][x1],
      mazeEl.children[y2 * width + x2], grid[y2][x2],
    )
  }

  let pos = start;
  let revisit = [];

  while (pos) {
    const next = randomEmptyAdjacent(pos);
    if (next) {
      carve(pos, next);
      revisit.push(pos);
      pos = next;
    } else {
      pos = revisit.pop();
    }
  }

  return grid;
}

const renderQueue = [];
const queue = (c1, v1, c2, v2) => {
  renderQueue.push(() => {
    renderCell(c1, v1);
    renderCell(c2, v2);

    const next = renderQueue.shift();
    if (next) requestAnimationFrame(next);
  });
}

const renderCell = (cellEl, cell) => {
  if (cell & 8) {
    cellEl.style.borderLeftColor = "transparent";
  }

  if (cell & 4) {
    cellEl.style.borderRightColor = "transparent";
  }

  if (cell & 2) {
    cellEl.style.borderBottomColor = "transparent";
  }

  if (cell & 1) {
    cellEl.style.borderTopColor = "transparent";
  }
}

const m = maze(40, 40);
renderQueue.shift()();
```

```css
.maze {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.cell {
  flex: none;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="maze"></div>
```

Comment: This still yields a maximum stack size exceeded error when the length and breadth are too large.

Comment: Are you sure? What numbers are you inputting? It was late when I wrote the code but I don't think there's any recursion here so I can't see how it could blow the stack.

Comment: This is a wonderful answer.  Thank you.  You're probably right these days that there is no longer a reason to use `setTimeout` to escape the stack, there was a time before WebWorkers when it was a very useful way to handle long-running processes without sacrificing responsiveness.